# Firestore: How to exempt a field from being indexed via java code

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store my fields in Firestore but exclude them from being index, that too via java coding us and not via Firestore console.

Is that possible to use the Java client Firestore library?
and if yes could you please suggest a method.

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude them from being index"? What exactly would you like to achieve?

Comment: Firestore is creating index for each field by default , my Aim is to exclude some filds from being indexed by firestore

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What are your concerns?

Comment: I just want to store that fields , and never query based on those fields and to save cost

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that programmatically in Java code. According to the official documentation regarding [single-field index exemption](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#single-field_index_exemptions):

> You can exempt a field from your [automatic indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing) settings by creating a single-field index exemption. An indexing exemption overrides the database-wide automatic index settings. An exemption can enable a single-field index that your automatic indexing settings would otherwise disable or disable a single-field index that automatic indexing would otherwise enable. For cases where exemptions can be useful, see the [indexing best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_best_practices).

So this can be **only** done in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), by accessing the Firestore database and selecting the <kbd>Indexes</kbd> tab. In the bottom part of the page you'll see a blue button called "Add exemption":

[image]

Comment: Thank you Alex Can it be done via firestore CLI or only option is console

Comment: As far as I know, it can be done only in the console. Please also note, that there is [a limit of 200 index exemptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_limits). So be aware of this limitation.

Comment: Hey Neha. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?